# Installing MS Office 2016 on new computer

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I installed MS Office 2016 Pro on a new computer and want to have it set up the same way I had it on my old computer - that is using PST files for mail, contacts, calendar, etc.  However, in the process of installing, I used some automated feature (I think) to set up the mailbox etc.  The set up then used my new MS account to setup Outlook data files which default to an email account using outlook, not gmail.  I don't want to use exchange, I just want to use the same pst file I had on my old computer with all my email, contacts, calendar, etc.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel, Mail, and delete the profile in the Profile section (you did not want this). Then use the Email Accounts section, set up a new Account and be sure not to use any wizards. I use this approach and do not use Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If You have a copy of your "old" .PST file, then yes it is possible, and there are several ways to do that and all of them are quite similar and depend on your desired end goal.

One way:  You could just add your old **PST** file to outlook

1. Go to **File** -> **Account Settings** -> **Data Files** -> **Add**
2. Browse for your old PST and finish adding it.

Now You will have all data from your old PST at your disposal, You can even make it to be your primary PST file, Archive it(to make it smaller), and after archiving don't forget to compact it, or something else.... If needed, I will give You more guidance, although google knows it all ;)

By default, outlook/exchange will cashe your emails inside your local PST file, which can be seen/tweaked at this location:
**File** -> **Account Settings** -> **Data Files** -> Click on your PST file -> Click on **Settings** tab -> Switch to **Advanced** tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your gmail with old PST file on the new computer, just configure your gmail account on your Outlook as POP and import your PST file. Then remove the outlook.com account .

If you want to use your Outlook.com account with the old PST file on the new computer and would not like to use Exchange. Just [re-configure your outlook.com as POP/IMAP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-email-account-using-advanced-setup-560a9065-3c3a-4ec5-a24f-cdb9a8d622a2#bkmk_advanced) on the new computer and import or open your PST file.(Before that, you need to enable POP/IMAP Access in Outlook.com)